# Symbol lookup error after replacing strings

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, elf

I tried to change a specific string in a shared library and after running the program that linked with it, I got this error:

```
./prog: symbol lookup error: /home/user/lib/libprog.so: undefined symbol: have_qwerty, version PROG_PRIVATE
```

The command to change the strings is:

```
sed -i "s/have_somewq/have_qwerty/g" ./libprog.so
```

In theory, this **should work** regardless, because this string is changed in all the files that use this library and in the whole library.

So what can be the problem here?
How can I fix or debug this issue?

Comment: *"In theory, this should work regardless..."* - you did not change it in your program `prog` and `prog` is not an argument to `sed` (or you did not state it). Are you certain those names are not sorted in some way?

Answer (score 2):

> sed -i "s/have_somewq/have_qwerty/g" ./libprog.so

Are you trying to change symbol name in binary file using sed? This isn't going to work. One reason is that in addition to symbol names shared libs also contain their hashvalues in dedicated sections which you won't be able to modify without lots of effort.

Also note that symbol has PROG_PRIVATE version which *may* mean that it's not meant to be used outside of the library.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question, Is there any public tool that does that? Like obfuscating the symbols?

Comment: I was once looking for something like this but found nothing and common knowledge was that it would be quite hard to implement.